# ggplot axis labels displaying in wrong timezone

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting rainfall data against date/time over a 3 day period. The data is irregular so I have binned them into hourly totals. When I plot this without and scale arguments it labels the x-axis with correctly with the month and date. I want the x-axis ticks to be every 6 hours for ease of viewing.

I attempted using:

```r
scale_x_datetime(labels = scales::date_format("%d-%m %H:00"),  breaks = "6 hours")
```

but this offsets the x-axis ticks and they are now delayed by 13 hours. This makes me think it is producing the x-axis labels using UTC (I am in NZ).

To fix this I attempted to set the timezone as follows:

```r
scale_x_datetime(labels = scales::date_format("%d-%m %H:00"),  breaks = "6 hours"), timezone = "Pacific/Auckland)
```

but this made no change.

Comment: It looks like the default timezone in the format statement is "UTC" try adding `tz = "NZ"` (your preferred tz) to the format statement.

Answer (score 1):

@Dave2e nailed it, thought I had already tried it but apparently not. Specifying timezone in the date_format as follows:

```r
scale_x_datetime(labels = scales::date_format("%d-%m %H:00", tz="Pacific/Auckland"),  breaks = "6 hours")
```

fixed the issue.